# Using multi-threading to pause my application does not behave as expected

Tags: java, javafx

I am designing a matching memory game, I am almost done with it and everything is working as it should be, however, when the user has opened two different cards the program won't pause(wait) few seconds so the user can see what the second card was. 
I have tried using a long for loop operation but encountered the same problem. I have tried Thread.sleep, TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep, Task and Platform.runLater.

The program opens the card and closes it instantly THEN it waits for the specified duration, keeping in mind that I am calling pauseThread after open and before close functions.

I have tried the above suggestions but they are leading me no where and I can't seem to find where the problem is with my code or where should I place the pauseThread. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MemoryMatchingGame extends Application{
    private static Card selectedCard=null;                  // This is to save a reference for the first card to use in comparison
    private static int numOfCorrectPairs = 0;       // Keeping track of how many cards the user got correct

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String[] images = {"C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\1.png",            // This is a string array to store images locations
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\2.png",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\3.jpg",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\4.jpg",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\5.jpg",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\6.png",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\7.jpg",
                "C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\Project#4\\8.jpg"};
        ArrayList<Card> listOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>();

        for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++) {                                            // This for loop will add each image twice to the array list
            listOfCards.add(new Card(images[i]));
            listOfCards.add(new Card(images[i]));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(listOfCards);                                               // Shuffling the deck of cards


        primaryStage.setTitle("Memory Matching Game");
        HBox hb = new HBox();

        VBox firstColoumn = new VBox();
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++) 
                firstColoumn.getChildren().add(listOfCards.get(i));
        VBox secondColoumn = new VBox();
            for(int i=4; i<8; i++) 
                secondColoumn.getChildren().add(listOfCards.get(i));
        VBox thirdColoumn = new VBox();
            for(int i=8; i<12; i++) 
                thirdColoumn.getChildren().add(listOfCards.get(i));
        VBox fourthColoumn = new VBox();
            for(int i=12; i<16; i++) 
                fourthColoumn.getChildren().add(listOfCards.get(i));

        hb.getChildren().addAll(firstColoumn, secondColoumn, thirdColoumn, fourthColoumn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 460, 450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class Card extends Button {
        private String imageLocation;       // To store the destination of the image
        private Image img;                  // To store a reference of the image to be used when setting graphic on a button

        public Card(String imageLocation) throws FileNotFoundException {
            this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageLocation);
            img = new Image(fis);

            setPrefSize(150, 150);

            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if(isCardOpen()==true)
                    return;             // To ensure no action is made once an image is already opened and the user clicked on it again

                if(selectedCard==null) {// This will test if the user has a card open already for comparison or not, if not it will store a reference to the card to use to compare once another card is opened
                    selectedCard = this;
                    open();
                }
                else {                  // If we enter this statement, this means the user has a card open already and we are ready to perform comparison

                    open();             // First action taken is to reveal the second card then perform comparison

                        if(this.isEqual(selectedCard)) {
                            numOfCorrectPairs++;
                            System.out.println("Got one");
                        }
                        else {
                            //Get program to pause here

                            Hold pauseThread = new Hold();
                            pauseThread.run();

                            System.out.println("After pausing");
                            this.close();
                            selectedCard.close();
                        }

                        selectedCard=null;      // This will nullify the variable so that we are able to perform comparison again for two other cards
                }                       // End of else statement

            });                         // End of actionHandler

            close();                    // This will ensure whenever a card is created it is set face-down
        }


        private void close() {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        public void open() {
            setGraphic(new ImageView(img));
            System.out.println("Open");
        }

        private boolean isCardOpen() {
            return this.getGraphic()!=null;
        }

        private boolean isEqual(Card selectedCard) {
            return this.imageLocation.equals(selectedCard.imageLocation);
        }
    }

    private class Hold extends Thread{
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get some coding ideas from [here](https://github.com/sedj601/CardMatchingFX/blob/master/src/cardmatchingfx/FXMLDocumentController.java).

Comment: Here are some thing I think you can do to improve your code. 1. Use `ImageView` instead of `Button` as your `Card`. 2. Use `PauseTranstition` so that the second card can be seen instead of a `Thread`. 3. Use `GridPane` instead of `VBox` and `HBox`. 4. Don't hard code links to images.

Comment: If you tried Platform.runLater() you should try again with the approach I gave below.  I use this approach frequently when I need to interact with the JavaFX thread from another thread.  Let us know if you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is running in the JavaFX Application Thread.  You don't want to pause this thread because it will lock your GUI.  As has already been mentioned, you are starting another thread and putting it to sleep, but this doesn't add delay to your GUI that is running in the JavaFX Thread.

An alternative approach would be to use Platform.runLater().  The Hold thread can invoke a method in the JavaFX thread that implements a Platform.runLater() runnable.  The runnable is a short lambda that holds the code to close the selected card.  The timing may vary slightly from 3000 ms, but you don't have much going on in the JavaFX thread and it doesn't seem critical for this application.

Here are the modifications to try.

First modify the Hold class to include a constructor to pass in the Card object.  Then call the closeAfterPause() method on card.

```
private class Hold extends Thread {
    private Card card;
    public Hold(Card card) {
        this.card = card;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            card.closeAfterPause();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the closeAfterPause() method in the MemoryMatchingGame class.

```
 private void closeAfterPause() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("After Pausing");
            close();
            selectedCard.close();
        });
    }
```

Then modify the else part of your if-else statement as follows

```
          else {
                    //Get program to pause here
                    Hold pauseThread = new Hold(this);
                    new Thread(pauseThread).start();
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tested your modifications and applied them, however, the console outputs the following: Open Open After pausing, then a NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why when I just use Thread.sleep in my main thread it won't sleep after the open call. I am calling Open first THEN I am using Thread.Sleep on my main thread and lastly i am calling the Close methods. Shouldn't it pause the entire GUI with both cards open for the specified time ?

Comment: I'm not sure where the NullPointerException is coming from, do you know which line of the code is causing it to throw?

Comment: I also corrected the way you were starting the thread.  See above.  You can't instantiate the class and then call the run method on the object.  To start the thread you need to use Thread().start.

Answer (score 0):

FX comes with a rich set of Animation/Timeline support - there's no need for falling back onto bare Threads. The most simple form of getting wait-for-xx is to use a Timeline configured with xx and an actionHandler that does something when ready:

```
Timeline holdTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.seconds(2),  e -> closeCards()));
```

Also it's a good idea to centralize all logic *outside* of a Control. Actually, you should never-ever extend a view for the purpose to include view-unrelated logic. So your long-time goal should be to

- extract all single card logic from Card into a CardModel which exposes properties like f.i. image, id, open, disposed
- use a plain Button, configure and bind its properties to model properties as appropriate
- centralize all game logic like timing, selecting, when opening is allowed, when succeed into a game controller

As I don't want to spoil your fun in doing that - I'll just post a little outline in the direction of the last bullet. Its responsibilities so far

- provide api to open a single card
- provide api to end a turn: either match or close cards
- internals to keep track of opened cards and timing

The snippets just re-mixes your code a bit, moving game logic from the button into the controller (aka: here simply the outer class) and setting the button's action handler to access the controller.

```
private Card firstCard; 
private Card secondCard;

private Timeline holdTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(2000),  e -> closeCards()));

public void closeCards() {
    if (firstCard == null || secondCard == null) {
        System.out.println("error!!");
        return;
    }
    if (firstCard.isEqual(secondCard)) {
        System.out.println("success");
        firstCard.setDisable(true);
        secondCard.setDisable(true);
        firstCard = null;
        secondCard = null;
    } else {
        firstCard.close();
        secondCard.close();
        firstCard = null;
        secondCard = null;
    }
}

public void openCard(Card card) {
    if (card.isCardOpen()) return;
    if (holdTimer.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) return;
    if (firstCard ==  null) {
        firstCard = card;
        firstCard.open();
    } else if (secondCard == null) {
        secondCard = card;
        secondCard.open();
        holdTimer.playFromStart();
    }
}

// Dont! dont, dont!!! ever extend a Control
//**TBD**: Move open/close state logic into a CardModel
// then configure a plain Button with the properies of that model
private class Card extends Button {
    private String imageLocation;       // To store the destination of the image
   // private Image img;                  // To store a reference of the image to be used when setting graphic on a button

    public Card(String imageLocation) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
        setPrefSize(150, 150);
        setOnAction(e -> openCard(this));
    }

    public void close() {
        setText("");
    }

    public void open() {
        setText(imageLocation);
        System.out.println("Open");
    }

    public boolean isCardOpen() {
        return getText() !=  null && getText().length() > 0;//this.getGraphic()!=null;
    }

    private boolean isEqual(Card selectedCard) {
        if (selectedCard == null) return false;
        return this.imageLocation.equals(selectedCard.imageLocation);
    }
}
```